# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy with common class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've already seen many questions about the same argument, but I didn't find any solution.
I've two classes that inherits the same class.

Basically:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class MyGeneric {
  private String idGeneric;
  public String getIdGeneric() {
    return idGeneric;
  }
  public void setIdGeneric(final String idGeneric) {
    this.idGeneric = idGeneric;
  }
}

@Entity
public class Child extends MyGeneric {
    // [some fields]
}


@Entity
public class Parent extends MyGeneric {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "idGeneric")
    private Child child;
}
```

But the application fails to run because:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: mypackage.Parent.child, referenced property unknown: mypackage.Child.idGeneric
```

I can't understand why it can find the property `Child.idGeneric` since it exists.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "idGeneric")`. it doesn't look like you want to specify inverse side of the association

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm beginning to think that's the only way. It's works.

Comment: How else would you expect it to work?

Comment: You're right, I see that's the way to do it properly.

Comment: @Michal could you write your comment as an answer? So I can accept it, thanks.

Comment: @Alessandro added my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not mapping the inverse side of the association, you cannot use mappedBy.
Replace you mapping with the following:

```
@OneToOne 
@JoinColumn(name = "idGeneric")
private Child child;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Child extends MyGeneric {
    // [some fields]
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")
    private Parent parent;
}

@Entity
public class Parent extends MyGeneric {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Child child;
}
```

The above association should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the parent must be generic, so I've used the class MyGeneric instead of Parent... but I get the same error.

Comment: The above example looks wrong, mappedBy is specified in the non-owning side of a bidirectional relationship.  Need to add OneToOne annotation to parent field of the Child class as owning side.